# Administration area in PHP (MVC)

Tags: php, zend-framework, administration

I was wondered what is the best way (and maybe the more secure) to organize the admin area.

First, what I mean by **administration area**, it is to manage the site itself (manage user, manage the cache, manage news, ...).

Currently, I have a **`User`** table, so that users can log into their member's area.
So is it better to **use the same table**, and add a user with special rights (administrator) or create another table only for administrators?

It also means having to manage multiple identities on the site (Member, Administrator).
What is the best way to proceed in Zend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imo... It would be better to use the same user table for authentication with a column to specify a role (ie user, admin etc).

Zend Framework has a built in authorization to log users in and built in ACL (access controll list) to allow users access to modules, controllers and actions based on their role.

There are lots of working examples on the web including the Zend framework docs.